# Is there anyway to update query field value when changing source table value

Tags: ms-access

I created a [Job card] query that have some database on [Base info] table Primary key value.
Sometimes there are 50~100 [Job card] relate to a [Job number]

At first, I thought that [Base info] table Primary key value (with deadline column) won't be changed, but because job fail and need to redo again so failed job number will be mark with fail.

ex:
302159984 (deadline column :2022/08/09) will be changed to 302159984fail1 (deadline column:2022/08/09)

and a new 302159984 (deadline column :2022/08/19) will be add to [base info] table.

we need 2 [job number] 302159984fail1 and 302159984 because it will be pay seprately. ex: 302159984fail1 go into 2022/08/09 report, but new 302159984 go into 2022/08/19 report.

But I need to keep existing [Job card query] records info from changing when [Base info] table Primary key value get changed or auto change existing [Job card] table info to match failed job number.

Op1: auto change existing record's data

```
[Base info] table info
          1 data (bangou):302159984
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
[Job card] table info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
[Job card] query info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
   
  after job failed:

[Base info] table info
          1 data (bangou):302159984fail1
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
existing[Job card] table info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984fail1
existing [Job card] query  info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984fail1
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
```

Op2: fix [job card query] record's data after Job card approved

```
[Base info] table info
          1 data (bangou):302159984
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
[Job card] table info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
existing [Job card] query  info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
   
  after job failed:

[Base info] table info
          1 data (bangou):302159984fail1
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
existing[Job card] table info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
existing [Job card] info:
          Input 1(noi dung): 21
          Input 2(moto):１２３1
          1 data (bangou):302159984
          3 data (deadline):2022/08/09
```

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVc2q.png)

Comment: If you change the key value then child records will no longer associate. If you want the child records foreign key to change, have you heard of "cascade update"?

Comment: If you used autonumber surrogate key instead of the natural key, relationships will not be impacted just because the [bangou] value is modified. Why do you show data duplicated in base and job info?

Comment: I just 1 days new to access, after some searching i can only get query to work if i input [job number] in to [job card]. When some sumbit a job card they only know [job number] so if i change key value to auto number query stop working.

Comment: 1 day? Any study? Spend a solid week with an introductory tutorial to learn relational database principles and Access functionality. If you use autonumber as primary key then it must be saved as foreign key in related table. Use form/subform for data entry. You haven't even provided an attempted query nor sample tables.

Comment: Acctually It needs alot of [Base info] in [Job card] for people to do that job. I just show deadline for example. So those infos need to come into sight after enter [job number].

Comment: My company want to change to acces from filemaker, but I have to look up all posibible and imposible with access in a short time so no time for me to properly learn access, just search and try bunch of function we need.

Comment: The point of relational database is to not duplicate same data across multiple tables. You retrieve related info with query joining tables. This is not the venue to learn basic concepts.

Comment: kind of undestand that. In [job card] table there just have input 1 input 2 and job number, all other infos just appear in query form. that the point of query right. but because some time [base info] get change so things get complicated.

Comment: So you either have to create a new [base info] record or save data you don't want to change in the job table. This is often an issue with data like product pricing, which can change over time. If you don't want users typing in this duplicate data, requires code (VBA or macro) to save from [base info] to job record.

Comment: OP1: is there anyway to make access change all existing [job card] table fields value that have relation with [base info] tables. ex: when [base info]'s[job number] change from 99 to 99fail, all existing record in [job card] table that contain [job number] 99 also auto change to 99fail.  OP2: it will need VBA or macro to duplicate data from [base info] table to [job card] table. I personally prefer OP1 to Op2

Comment: I already answered that in first comment. If tables have a defined relationship and Cascade Update is set and [Job Number] is the primary key, changing it will propagate to related records. Do research on that feature. Of course, that is only for the key, other fields cannot do this.

Comment: i will try to learn about Cascade Update